# contour plot of a circle by 3 vectors

Tags: matlab, contour

I have some nodes on a circle, and the value of a function on these points, so I have 3 vectors(x,y,z) that I want to plot it by contour.

I tried contour by using griddata to  find the circle figure. but my figure is not true,

In fact I need to a way for plotting without griddate.(without interpolation), like when use trimesh.

I use MATLAB 2009 and I could not find tricontour. Is there any suggestion?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you provide your code, what you tried so far and what you expect as a result? Why don't you want to use griddata with inerpolation?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is completely unclear to me what you want to achieve and what you are asking. You have to be way more precise and explicit if you want an answer.

Comment: I have in u0(the third vector ) some value like 2.7, but when I use griddata all values of  Zq is lower than 1. by use  the following code ,the result is a circle but the value of Zq is not true. 

      xq=min(x):(max(x)-min(x))/200:max(x);

 yq=min(y):(max(y)-min(y))/200:max(y);

[Xq, Yq] = meshgrid(xq,yq);
Zq =griddata(x,y,u0,Xq,Yq);
contourf(Xq,Yq,Zq);

Comment: when the length of the vectors are square of a number like 144, I construct 3 matrices by a loop. In these cases I do not have problem, but most of the time the length is not square of a number

Comment: @Rosa, thanks for trying to clarify, but: please don't comment, but edit your question so it become more clear. Best way to write a question: provide a tiny (!) bit of context, then describe what you are working with, then describe what you want to achieve, then describe what you tried in order to achieve that, then describe where exactly (!) you got stuck. The best thing to do is to include a short piece of code that we can actually take and run in Matlab, so we can see where you arrived at and what doesn't work. – Getting a good answer necessitates putting some effort into the question.